# Separate children behaviour input on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, selection

https://codepen.io/btek/pen/qBjaddP

I'm trying to separate this selection on select , to select only options from one product.

I was trying each() , children().

```
$('[name="subscribe"], [name="not_subscribe"]').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    var isSubscribe = $(event.target).val() === 'subscribe';

    if ($(event.target).prop("checked")) {
      $('input[type="checkbox"][value="not_subscribe"]').prop('checked', !isSubscribe);
      $('input[type="checkbox"][value="subscribe"]').prop('checked', isSubscribe);
      $('[data-amrecurring="recurring-settings"]').toggle(isSubscribe);
    } else {
      $('input[type="checkbox"][value="not_subscribe"]').prop('checked', isSubscribe);
      $('input[type="checkbox"][value="subscribe"]').prop('checked', !isSubscribe);
      $('[data-amrecurring="recurring-settings"]').toggle(!isSubscribe);
    }



  }.bind(this));
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, but it is clear you do not need the .off and the .bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved your code to JSFiddle for my convenience. I only changed the javascript.

I split the events between "Unsubscribe" and "Subscribe" and found the items you need with two functions: [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(event.target).parents('form').find('[name="not_subscribe"]').prop('checked', false);
$(event.target).parents('form').find('[data-amrecurring="recurring-settings"]').toggle(true);
```

And `toggle` here is not necessary, you know the state you want. Use instead `show` and `hide` without parameters.

```
$(event.target).parents('form').find('[data-amrecurring="recurring-settings"]').show();
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wcrbfsy6/1/)